# Oracle Transparent Application Continuity and JAVA

Tags: java, oracle

Well in my testing of Oracle TAC I seem to have run into a roadblock.  Since I am a DBA and not a Java developer that may be the reason.  Here is what I have.  TAC works when running via SQLPLUS so I know the service is setup correctly. Yet when I run it using a Java app it fails with the following error.

```
Dec 14, 2023 12:57:43 PM oracle.jdbc.replay.driver.TxnFailoverManagerImpl throwOriginalExceptionWithReplayError
WARNING: U:thread-1 main On CONN$$$Proxy@db57326, replay failed in method executeUpdate, error code: 384, reason: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-17384: Replay is disabled by server Continuity Management: executeUpdate
```

Now in my Java code I have it setup using UCP like this.

```
        String CONN_FACTORY_CLASS_NAME = "oracle.jdbc.replay.OracleDataSourceImpl";
        String ORACLE_WALLET = "c:\\oracle\\wallet";
        String TNS_ADMIN = "C:\\oracle\\product\\19.3.0\\client_1\\network\\admin";
        String WALLET_URL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:hr/myuser@pdb_tac";
        System.setProperty("oracle.net.tns_admin", TNS_ADMIN);
        System.setProperty("oracle.net.wallet_location", "(SOURCE=(METHOD=FILE)(METHOD_DATA=(DIRECTORY=" + ORACLE_WALLET + ")))");
         
        PoolDataSource pds = PoolDataSourceFactory.getPoolDataSource();
        pds = PoolDataSourceFactory.getPoolDataSource();
        pds.setConnectionFactoryClassName(CONN_FACTORY_CLASS_NAME);
        pds.setURL(WALLET_URL);
        pds.setConnectionPoolName("JDBC_UCP_POOL");
        pds.setInitialPoolSize(5);
        pds.setMinPoolSize(5);
        pds.setMaxPoolSize(20);
        pds.setTimeoutCheckInterval(5);

        //enable FAN and connection tests
        pds.setFastConnectionFailoverEnabled(true);
        pds.setValidateConnectionOnBorrow(true);

        //disable auto-commit
        pds.setConnectionProperty(OracleConnection.CONNECTION_PROPERTY_AUTOCOMMIT, "false");
        pds.setConnectionProperty(OracleConnection.CONNECTION_PROPERTY_IMPLICIT_STATEMENT_CACHE_SIZE, "100");

        // Default is 0. Set the maximum time, in seconds, that a
        // connection remains available in the connection pool.
        //this line allows the pool push connections in and out of each node.
        pds.setInactiveConnectionTimeout(10);
      
        //Validate connection has nothing to do with reconnections
        pds.setValidateConnectionOnBorrow(true);
        pds.setSQLForValidateConnection("select 1 from dual");

        Connection conn = pds.getConnection();
        DbUpdate2 self = new DbUpdate2();
        //conn = dataSource.getConnection();
        conn.setAutoCommit(false);
        self.getInstanceName(conn);

        String var10000 = self.getInstanceName(conn);
        System.out.println("Instance Name = " + var10000);
        System.out.println("Kill node and wait after press any key:" + var10000 );

        self.pressAnyKeyToContinue();
        System.out.println("Wait while 5000 records updated");

        //uncomment to test with spy table
        self.doTx(conn,numValue);
```

What am I missing here?  Thanks in advance.